# How to get $context in a twig rendered via shortcode in Timber?

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I have a shortcode in a post [shortcode]. I would like to be able to access the title of the current post within the shortcode, but `$context` is blank Is there any way to get access to the `post` from within a twig rendered via shortcode?

Here is example code:

```
add_shortcode('include', 'timber_partial_shortcode');

function timber_partial_shortcode($atts){
    $post = new TimberPost()
    $context['post'] = $post
    $name = sanitize_text_field($atts['name']);
    return Timber::compile('partials/' . $name . '.twig', $context);
}
```

This is working for now but I am wondering if there is a way to access a TimberPost in a twig file that has been already set rather than resetting it.. and if I'd like variables from $context, `Timber::getContext()` throws an undefined function error from within the shortcode.

Answer (score 3):

@damon try `Timber::get_context();` :)

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Comment: derp.

any way to pass it in from outside though? seems expensive to have to redo all the context/post stuff when it's already in a post...

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the `get_context()` function.

- If you call `get_context()`, all the values that are set in context are cached.
- Whenever you call `get_context()` again, it will just return the cached context.
- This means, that you can’t add new values to the context after you called `get_context()` the first time, e.g. through the `timber/context` filter.

I think that [Jared’s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528654/) answer is actually pretty much on point. Since he’s the creator of Timber, I guess he has to know ;).

But since you asked how you could pass in a value to a function from outside in the context of shortcodes and Timber, I’ll try to show you some options you have:

### Work with an anonymous function

In your template file, you could add your shortcode with an anonymous function as the callback (second parameter). This way, you can take advantage of the `use` keyword, with which you can pass in the `$context` defined before.

```
<?php

use Timber\Timber;

$context = Timber::get_context();

$post = Timber::get_post();
$context['post'] = $post;

// Add shortcode with an anonymous function
add_shortcode( 'include', function( $atts ) use ( $context ) {
    $name = sanitize_text_field( $atts['name'] );
    return Timber::compile( 'partials/' . $name . '.twig', $context );
} );

Timber::render( 'shortcodes.twig', $context );
```

However, if you use that shortcode in multiple template files, you probably don’t want to add that function every time. Let’s see what we can do about this:

### Create a filter to pass on context

Template file (e.g. **post.php**)

```
<?php

use Timber\Timber;

$context = Timber::get_context();

$post = Timber::get_post();
$context['post'] = $post;

set_context_for_shortcodes( $context );

Timber::render( 'shortcodes.twig', $context );
```

**functions.php**

```
/**
 * Add a filter that simply returns the context passed to this function.
 *
 * @param $context
 */
function set_context_for_shortcodes( $context ) {
    add_filter( 'get_context', function( $empty = array() ) use ( $context ) {
        return $context;
    } );
}

add_shortcode( 'include', function( $atts ) {
    // Get the context trough the filter set before
    $context = apply_filters( 'get_context', [] );

    $name = sanitize_text_field( $atts['name'] );
    return Timber::compile( 'partials/' . $name . '.twig', $context );
} );
```

However, be aware that when you use anonymous functions with actions and filters, [you cannot remove them later with `remove_action()` or `remove_filter()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45901/passing-a-parameter-to-filter-and-action-functions). So when you develop a plugin or theme that you will publish, you might reconsider this. Otherwise, you’re probably good to go.

### Handle shortcodes with a class

There’s another option you have, which doesn’t rely on a filter, but on a class handling your shortcodes.

Template file (e.g. **post.php**)

```
<?php

use Timber\Timber;

$context = Timber::get_context();

$post = Timber::get_post();
$context['post'] = $post;

new Shortcode_Handler( $context );

Timber::render( 'shortcodes.twig', $context );
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

class Shortcode_Handler {
    public $context;

    public function __construct( $context ) {
        $this->context = $context;

        add_shortcode( 'include', array( $this, 'timber_partial_shortcode' ) );
    }

    public function timber_partial_shortcode( $atts ) {
        $context = $this->context;

        $name = sanitize_text_field( $atts['name'] );
        return Timber::compile( 'partials/' . $name . '.twig', $context );
    }
}
```

Comment: what happen if I want pass other variable to twig shortcode file, I think I will push new variable to that `$context`?

Comment: @Kyle Exactly. You can fill `$context` with all the variables you need in your Twig file before you pass it to `Timber::render()` or `Timber::compile()`. Example: `$context['additionalvariable'] = $youradditionalvariable;`.